# Chrome devtools behaves differently after adding a comment

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

In chrome devtools, when I input

```
> {a:1}
```

I got `{ a: 1 }` object as the return value, which is understandable.

But when I add a comment after it

```
> {a:1}//
```

The return value becomes `1`.

[image: screenshot]

It might be a trivial question but it does make me scratch my head for a long time.

I assume the devtool interprets the `{}` as a code block and `a` as a tag name. But why adding a comment `//` would make such a difference? Is it the intended behavior?

Comment: I imagine their command line tools look for a simple expression.  The second one doesn't match the pattern for a simple expression.  Remember that the dev tools command line is just a debug tool.  What you're doing will never happen in real web code.  Having said that, you could argue this is a bug and file a bug report.

Comment: I also tried this in node.js and Safari, the result remains the same. So I guess it is actually a global phenomenon with a consistent rule?

Comment: This is pretty interesting. I could understand if the output of the second one was a string serialized version of the object, but not sure why if grabs the value of the "a" key and outputs that.

I also find this pretty interesting: `var temp="hello";{b:42}`. It outputs "42". So seems anything apart from giving just the object has this behavior.

Comment: And having more than one key/value i.e. `{a:3,b:7}//` results in "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'"

Comment: In statement mode it's a block and `a` is a *label*, `1` is just a literal number, which is the last expression in the block so it becomes the result of the block's evaluation. When you add a second label it becomes invalid syntax because labels can't be inside an expression (`1` starts the expression, the comma is a part of it).